# UITextField Border Colour with IBDISPOSABLE

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a custom view `UITextField` that will render in Interface Builder.

I want to be able to adjust the border colour and width.

I understand that I need to implement `IBINSPECTABLE` and `IBDESIGNABLE` in order to make these changes and see them in my Storyboard.

My header file is as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface BorderTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic) IBINSPECTABLE UIColor borderColor;

@end
```

which isn't working for the border colour. I know I'm doing something wrong I'm just not sure what.

Comment: I think it's IBInspectable.
http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo - I've corrected it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try the Layer Property of UITextField

Try like below.

```
UITextField *txtField = // Initialize your txtField
txtField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].cgcolor;
txtField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Hope this solve your problem

Comment: Thank you, I know how to do this in code. What I want to do is implement IBDESIGNABLE so I can make and see the changes in my storyboard.